# Using Autoencoders to denoise timeseries

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, neural-networks, autoencoders, smoothing

I've been trying to use Autoencoders to denoise time series using R. In my script, I create a function that receives the **series** to be denoised (as a vector) and the number of lagged observations **numLag** that will be used to denoise each observation (like a moving average window).  First, I create a dataframe **df** in which each column is a lagged version of **series**. For instance, if **numLag** equals 10, than **df** will have 11 columns. After that, I fit an Autoencoder to **df** and then use the encoder to obtain denoised values for my time series. Here's the function:

```
AE_smooth = function(numLag = 10, 
                     numEpoch = 500,
                     batchSize = 32,
                     act = "sigmoid",
                     series){
  
  df = data.frame(series = series) 
  
  for(i in 1:numLag){
    lag = paste0("lag",i)
    df[,lag] = data.table::shift(series,i)
  }
  
  df = na.omit(df) |>
    as.matrix()
  
  input = layer_input(shape = numLag)
  
  encoded = input |>
    layer_dense(units = 1,
                activation = act) 
  
  decoded = encoded |>
    layer_dense(units = numLag,
                activation = act)
  
  autoencoder = keras_model(input, decoded)
  encoder = keras_model(input, encoded)
  
  autoencoder |> compile( 
    optimizer = optimizer_adam(),
    loss = 'mean_squared_error'
  )
  
  autoencoder |> fit( # Fitting model
    df[,-1],df[,-1],
    epochs = numEpoch,
    batch_size = batchSize,
    shuffle = FALSE,
    validation_data = list(df[,-1],df[,-1]),
    verbose = 1
  )
  
  smooth = predict(encoder,df[,-1]) |> 
    as.vector() 
  
  smooth = c(rep(NA,numLag),smooth)
  
  return(smooth)
}
```

The problem is: in addition to not being able to smooth properly, the function ends up returning different smoothed series for the same hyperparameters. I chose a certain set of hyperparameters and ran the exact same model 12 different times until convergence, but sometimes I get a denoised series (red) like this:

[image]

and other times I get some kind of inversion of the denoised series:

[image]

Any ideas on how I can improve my model? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any reason why can't you use one of the many simple and battle-tested time-series smoothing tools available?

Comment: Because my goal is to compare a more complex model like the Autoencoder to these simple models you are mentioning.

Comment: This is a known issue with Keras models. They are not reproducible out of box.

Comment: This might be very similar to PCA, which projects data unto linear subspaces. Each subspace is equivalently spanned by either a principal component vector or its negative. Some algorithms "fix" the decomposition by ensuring the first element of every PC / score is non-negative. Here you might as well have a similar situation, since autoencoders also project data unto lower-dimensional manifolds. My guess is that the solution would be to somehow ensure that the sign of the first element of the corresponding weight is non-negative.